# Pi Zero W: Connect keyboard AND act as hidg0 keyboard?

Tags: usb, pi-zero-w, keyboard

I have my Pi Zero W acting as a keyboard via the `/dev/hidg0` method. That works fine.

However, I'd also like to connect a keyboard to the Pi at the same time to control the Pi without using SSH.

What sort of USB hub or cables would I need to allow a USB keyboard to interact with the Pi *AND* allow the Pi to act as a hidg0 device to send keystrokes to another computer?

Comment: I don't think you can do this as there is only the one USB port, and it must be in either master *or* slave mode, it can't be both.  And you need a master to connect a keyboard and a slave to connect as one.   I do not think there is the potential to do that with, eg., just one port on a hub (really it is the hub that is in whatever mode, not individual ports).  I could be wrong on the last point though.

Comment: Considered a Bluetooth keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line:

- Pi Zero **cannot** be used as *both* a USB Host and a USB Slave
- Pi 3 (and possibly Pi 4) **can** do it, see: [RPI acting both as slave and as master device on its usb ports - Raspberry Pi Forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=236706)